# Need to list all channel:entries, and do something different on "some" of them

Tags: entries

I have a need to pull all entries (in this case only 20 or so) from a channel, and have 5 random results do something different to the other 15. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to list 20 entries in random order and display the first 5 differently or do you want to output 20 and randomly treat 5 of them differently?

Comment: The latter. Basically, we want a grid of results (3 columns, x rows) and every so often one of the results is to display a thumbnail image. Completely randomly. Not my idea :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a plugin already written that does this, but it'd be pretty easy to write one or, use PHP in the template to do the same thing.

Basically, you want to generate a list of entries to be selected first, outside the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair.

Then, inside the tag pair, you'll just check to see if the current `{count}` is in the array.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
   $max = 20;
   $numels = 5;
   $range = range(0, $max);
   $vals = array_rand($range, $numels);
?>

{exp:channel:entries ... }
   <?php if(in_array('{count}', $vals)):?>random-entry<?php endif;?>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: That's a better way than the one I used, and pretty obvious too. Yet I could not think of it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the end like so:

```
<?php
$randoms = array();
?>
{exp:channel:entries channel="styleguide" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" limit="5" orderby="random"}
<?php
array_push($randoms, '{entry_id}');
?>
{/exp:channel:entries}

<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="styleguide" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination|trackbacks" dynamic="no" orderby="title" sort="asc"}
    <li>
        <?php
        if (in_array('{entry_id}', $randoms)) {
            echo 'hoorah';
        }
        ?>
    </li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Except I removed the first entries pair and replaced it with a simple SQL query.